# react-native navigation stack set push component then cover parent page

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-stack

Main page have two stack screens

and ones screen has description text. other screen has button and show other stck view

this is main

```
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Calc from './Calc';
import Complete from './Complete';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function Home() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initailRouteName="Calc">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Calc"
        component={Calc}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />

      <Stack.Screen
        style={styles.preview}
        name="Complete"
        component={Complete}
        options={{title: 'complate', headerShown: true}}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}


this is calc
  return (
  <Pressable onPress={() => navigation.push('Complete')}>
        <Text>calc</Text>
      </Pressable>
)
```

this is complate view [image: compage view]

how to i remove home text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be I Think take a look main stack.

I mean the home view where call? or show?

would you

```
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={Home}
    options={{
      headerShown: false,
      
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this option to your home screen instead of your nested screen, basically adding it to the top level navigator and not the nested navigator

```
options={{headerShown: false}}
```

also be careful of this typo :

```
initailRouteName 
//should be
initialRouteName
```

Answer (score 0):

react-navigation v6

headerShown: false

```
function Home() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initailRouteName="Calc"
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Calc"
        component={Calc}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />

      <Stack.Screen
        style={styles.preview}
        name="Complete"
        component={Complete}
        options={{title: 'complate', headerShown: true}}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```